# How to identify feature from multiple layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tools, identify

I have recently migrated from ArcGIS to QGIS.

Is there any way to identify a feature having multiple layers? I am currently working with about 400 shape files and need to know which is the one I'm currently working on. When I click the polygon I want to identify with the identify tool nothing happens unless I have the layer selected in the layer panel. The same happens with the selection tool.

How can I fix this? In ArcGIS I could identify any feature without having it selected on the layer list and I've looked through the settings of QGIS and found nothing.

Comment: QGIS version ? Did you try to "right click" ?

Comment: I have QGis 2.14.0. Yes I have tried to right click, but it doesn't select/identify the feature unless the layer is selected in the panel

Comment: Selected or visible ?

Comment: Selected, it doesn't matter if it's visible or not as long it is selected in the layer panel.

Comment: I can't reproduce with the "i" tool.

Comment: [I recorded my problem](http://i.imgur.com/89LtXyf.gifv). When I had QGis 2.8 it had the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. To do selection for all layers, you need to install a plugin called "Multiple Layer Selection"

   Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> search for "Multiple Layer Selection"

Click on the selection icon and you can select across the layers without the need to go to layer panel to select the layer first.

2. To identify the features without selecting each layer from the panel, do the following:

from the `Identify Results panel -> go to Mode located at the bottom of the panel and select Top down, stop at first`, as you can see in the image below

[image]

You can also test other options to get the mode option that fits your needs.

Comment: This appears to be built in now (no longer requiring a plug-in), at least as of 3.2.0.

Comment: @jpmc26 - can you describe where to find the tool? I've been looking for it but must be a little bit blind.

Comment: @Johanna If you open the Identify results window (for example by using the Identify tool on the map), there's a Mode dropdown at the bottom. Just as the answer describes. It's pretty much right where the image shows.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Thanks for your quick response, but I am still not making much sense of my results. I have a park with playground equipment, paths, structures, bike racks etc in separate layers. I want to select them all and find the IDs for all of the items. When I use the Information tool and look at the results I only get the items that are in one layer.

Comment: EDITED: I changed the Mode to Top Down and can now see all the layers. I think I'm OK now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I know that is not a best way to resolve your issue but you can try to add layer name like an ID attribute with using field calculator and label layer with it.

[image]